# Alineación de elementos con FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy realizando una web de viajes, estoy teniendo problemas con la alineación de los elementos de la sección tendencias, adjunto una foto de como debería quedar y adjunto el código, me gustaría saber si esta bien encarado el desarrollo ya que próximamente tengo que hacerlo responsive.

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://xd.adobe.com/view/bece1886-2d39-4a2d-7edd-5ded2d62c3f7-c8ff/screen/799c061c-1868-4ce0-99ff-13778cd8e3cf/Blog-Viajes-Desktop-1366?fullscreen)

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
}

body{
  width: 1150px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
/*Encabezado*/
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

/*Logo Principal*/
.logo{
 padding: 0 75px;
}

nav{
  padding: 0 75px;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.black{
  color: #2A3037;
  
}

.opacity{
  color: #CBD0D3;
}



/*Imagen de portada principal*/
.principal-cover{
  background-image: url(../img/Viajes_Hero.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  /* height: 0; */
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 0%;
}


/*Icono texto america del sur*/

.logo-map img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 120px;

}



/*Texto America del Sur*/
.text-image{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

/*Texto debajo del h1 america del sur*/
.subtitle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 270px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:420px;
}

/*Descripción america del sur*/
.subtitle-description{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 330px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Recuadro con información del destino*/
.rectangle-info{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: 800px;
  background-color: #2A3037;
  height: 140px;
  width: 220px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
}
/*Logo recuadro con información del destino*/
.logo-text .arrow-icon{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-top: 23px;
}
/*icono flecha*/
.arrow-icon{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.text-red{
  color:#FA6980;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


.text-white{
  color:#fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.text-description{
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*Titulo tendencias */
.title-tendencies{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
}

/*Imagenes seccion tendencias */

.tendencies-container{
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ejercicio Aenima</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
   <img width="90px" class="logo" src="logo/logo_01.svg" alt="Logo">
   <nav class="nav-bar">
  <a class="nav-link black" href="#">HOME</a>
  <a class="nav-link opacity" href="#">TENDENCIAS</a>
  <a class="nav-link opacity" href="#">BLOG</a>
   </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="container principal-cover">
   <div>
  <div class="logo-map">
    <img class="resp_img" width="30px" src="iconos/ic_pin.svg" alt="mapa">
  </div>
  <h1 class="text-image">AMÉRICA DEL SUR</h1>
  <h3 class="subtitle">Lugares maravillosos por America del Sur</h3>
  <p class="subtitle-description">Estos son algunos lugares que elijen la mayoría de los turistas que<br>visitan America del Sur</p>
  <div class="rectangle-info">
    <div class="logo-text">
   <img class="arrow-icon" src="iconos/arrow.svg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <p class="text-red">PRÓXIMA AVENTURA</p>
    <p class="text-white">Europa Meridional</p>
    <p class="text-description">Forman parte veinte países <br>ej.España,Francia,etc.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <h3 class="title-tendencies">TENDENCIAS</h3>
  <div class="tendencies-container">
   <div class="tendencies-item">
    <img class="image-text" src="img/card_01.png" alt="card1">
    <h5>Montañas y magia</h5>
    <p>Aquí la descripción para<b>Montañas y magia</b></p>
   </div>
   <div class="tendencies-item">
    <img src="img/card_02.png" alt="card2">
    <h5>Playa y sol</h5>
    <p>La descripción de <b>Playa y sol</b>debe ser esta</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tendencies-item">
    <img src="img/card_03.png" alt="card3">
    <h5>Nieve y aventura</h5>
    <p>Contiene la información de <b>Nieve y aventura</b></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, 2 comentarios: ¿por qué duplicas el texto de tu pregunta?, no es necesario; alcanza con redactar de forma clara la dificultad presentada, segundo al menos a mi no me terminar de quedar claro los elementos que quieres alinear, en que eje los quieres alinear...

Comment: Lo de duplicar el texto, es porque me dice siempre que mi pregunta es mayormente código y no me deja formularla, los quiero alinear en linea pero con un pequeño espacio entre ellos, ya probe con la propiedad space-around y no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se me hizo un tanto difícil entender el código que estás usando para maquetar dicha web, propongo que:

- Los segmentos donde esta la información sobre: *América del sur* y *próxima aventura* los agregues dentro de un `div` respectivamente a cada uno
- Lo anterior para poder desde el contenedor padre con *flexbox* modificar su `display`
- A la sección de *Tendencias* le agregue también un `display: flex;` para poder alinear sobre el *main-axis* a los 3 elementos que posees
- Reacomodé lo que a mi criterio sería un mejor modo de agrupar los links dentro de una etiqueta `ul` y cada etiqueta `a` dentro de un `li`
- También para dar la separación entre los tres *items* que son tendencia hago uso de `space-around` para dar un espacio entre ellos y a la izquierda y a la derecha
- Finalmente para poder acomodar la caja de texto que dice *Próxima Aventura* le doy un `margin-top: 250px;` para poder moverlo de arriba hacia abajo y que este un poco mas abajo con relación del otro elemento.

> Te recomiendo revises de nuevo el código que te propongo para los cambios que llevé a cabo, los cuales fueron parte para *tratar* de hacer mas manejable la maquetación y en segunda para *nuevamente* tratar de lograr el resultado esperado.

**Propuesta de código**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejercicio Aenima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .text-image {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .subtitle {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .subtitle-description {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
      }
      .principal-cover {
        background-color: peru;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: space-around;
        color: white;
      }

      .tendencies-group {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;

      }
      .tendencies-item {
        background-color: steelblue;
        border-radius: 10px;

      }
      .logo-text {
        font-size: 10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
        margin-top: 250px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
        border: dashed;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
      }
      .nav-bar {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex: auto;
      }
      .nav-bar__link, .nav-bar__link-active {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
      }
      .nav-bar__link-active {
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <!--<img width="90px" class="logo" src="logo/logo_01.svg" alt="Logo">-->
      <span>Aquí iría el logo</span>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">TENDENCIAS</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link-active" href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container principal-cover">
        <div class="rectangle-info">
            <h1 class="text-image">AMÉRICA DEL SUR</h1>
            <h3 class="subtitle">Lugares maravillosos por America del Sur</h3>
            <p class="subtitle-description">Estos son algunos lugares que elijen la mayoría de los turistas que<br>visitan America del Sur</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logo-text">
          <!--<img class="arrow-icon" src="iconos/arrow.svg" alt="logo">-->
          <p class="text-red">PRÓXIMA AVENTURA</p>
          <p class="text-white">Europa Meridional</p>
          <p class="text-description">Forman parte veinte países <br>ej.España,Francia,etc.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-tendencies">
        <h3 class="title-tendencies">TENDENCIAS</h3>
            <div class="tendencies-group">
                <div class="tendencies-item">
                  <!--<img class="image-text" src="img/card_01.png" alt="card1">-->
                  <h5>Montañas y magia</h5>
                  <p>Aquí la descripción para<b>Montañas y magia</b></p>
                </div>
                <div class="tendencies-item">
                    <!--<img src="img/card_02.png" alt="card2">-->
                    <h5>Playa y sol</h5>
                    <p>La descripción de <b>Playa y sol</b>debe ser esta</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tendencies-item">
                    <!--<img src="img/card_03.png" alt="card3">-->
                    <h5>Nieve y aventura</h5>
                    <p>Contiene la información de <b>Nieve y aventura</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

*Nota final*

> Te dejo la inclusión de las imágenes a ti